# How to run a class again after is has been initialised

Tags: ios, swift, nscoder, macaw

I have a graph which I want to load with data with recent results.

[Here is a screenshot to show you what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl5X4.png)

I am able to display the initial data correctly, however after that I cannot update the view to display the new data added to it.

The graph is a view on storyboard with custom class MacawChartView.

```
class ViewControllerResultsView: ViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

@IBOutlet var chartView: MacawChartView!    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    chartView.frame = CGRect(x: w/2 - (w * 0.95)/2, y: h * 0.57, width: w * 0.95, height: w * 0.45)
    chartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 253/255, green: 254/255, blue: 149/255, alpha: 1)
    chartView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    MacawChartView.playAnimations()
```

I have tried a lot of different ways to 're-run' the graph so it rebuilds with updated data but cannot get passed the 'coder aDecoder: NSCoder' argument required. Here is the initialiser in MacawChartView.swift

```
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(node: MacawChartView.createChart(), coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Thanks for any help. Please let me know if more information is needed etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation isn't great for this library, but here's a solution for you.  I started with the example project on gitHub, but I removed the `init` function and made the data `var`

```
class CustomMacawView: MacawView {

static var data: [Double] = [101, 142, 66, 178, 92]
static let palette = [0xf08c00, 0xbf1a04, 0xffd505, 0x8fcc16, 0xd1aae3].map { val in Color(val: val)}


public func updateData(newData : [Double])
{
    CustomMacawView.data = newData
    updateDisplay()
}

public func updateDisplay()
{
    let chart = CustomMacawView.createChart()
    self.node = Group(contents: [chart])
}
```

in my main view controller, I have a button to generate new data

```
@IBAction func cmdUpdateGraph(_ sender: Any) {
    macawView.updateData(newData: [Double.random(in: 1...100),
                                   Double.random(in: 1...100),
                                   Double.random(in: 1...100),
                                   Double.random(in: 1...100),
                                   Double.random(in: 1...100)]) }
```

Comment: That solution word! Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool, happy to help.  If you like the answer, you should accept it...

Comment: @Russell I tried to do like you but it shows the same chart :) (but the data changes). Please can you see my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63216461/value-changed-but-the-chart-doesnt-swift